# How to find index of a dictionary key value within a list? (python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Lets say I have a list such as:

```
listofpeople = [{'Jack': ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']}, {'Barry': ['Red', 'Green', 'Orange']}]
```

If I were to go about searching for the index of 'Jack', how would I find his index if 'Jack' is a key value of a dictionary within a list?

Comment: can the dictionary in list have multiple keys?
suchas

```listofpeople = [{'Jack': ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green'], 'Rose':['Black','White']}, {'Barry': ['Red', 'Green', 'Orange']}]```

Comment: Yes, the different names would be the multiple keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> listofpeople = [{'Jack': ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']}, {'Barry': ['Red', 'Green', 'Orange']}]
>>> [i for i, d in enumerate(listofpeople) if "Jack" in d.keys()]
[0]
```

Answer (score 7):

Keeping it simple -

```
for people in listofpeople:
    if 'Jack' in people:
        idx = listofpeople.index(people)
        break
```

If idx has a value at the end you have the index of the element that had 'jack' as a key

Comment: Just a note: if you only expect the name to appear once (or just care about recording the first occurence) you can avoid iterating over the whole dictionary by adding `break` after `idx = ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l = [{'Jack': ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']}, {'Barry': ['Red', 'Green', 'Orange']}]
>>> import itertools as it
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x[1] == 'Jack', enumerate(it.chain(*l))))
[(0, 'Jack')]
```

I am unpacking the variable `l` into positional arguments, which I then pass to [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). This results in a flat list with the values `['Jack', 'Barry']`. The built-in function `enumerate()` returns a tuple containing a count (starts from 0) and the values obtained from iterating over iterable. The next and last thing I do is filtering with small anonymous function all the tuples where the second element (`x[1]`) equals to the desired `str`.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, please don't look up the presence of a dictionary key from the list returned by `d.keys()`. Much more efficient is to query the dictionary directly. (Disclaimer: apparantly this only applies to Python 2, as the view returned in Python 3 also enables efficient membership tests...)

Then you can just fetch the index of the first item that has the key, e.g., like this:

```
idx = next((i for i,d in enumerate(listofpeople) if "Jack" in d), None)
```

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: Do we need try block here?. Just `idx = next(i for i,d in enumerate(listofpeople) if "Jack" in d, None)` is enough?`

Comment: surprisingly this answer is slower on my machine than casualcoder's

Comment: @YannicHamann That might be because the list is pretty short, s.t. looking up the index returns immediately. Plus, there is less function call / iterator wrapping overhead ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jack_indices = [i for i in range(len(listofpeople)) if listofpeople[i].keys() == ['Jack']]
```

Alternatively, if your dictionaries can have multiple keys and you're looking for all indices of those which contain 'Jack' as a key you could do:

```
jack_indices = [i for i in range(len(listofpeople)) if 'Jack' in listofpeople[i].keys()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
listofpeople = [{'Jack': ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']}, {'Barry': ['Red', 'Green', 'Orange']}]
idx = 0
for i in listofpeople:
  for j in i.keys():
    if j == 'Jack':
      print(idx)
      break
  idx += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = "Jack"
for index, value in enumerate(listofpeople):
    if name in value.keys():
        print('{} at index {}'.format(value, index))
>>>{'Jack': ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']} at index 0
```

Comment: Please consider improving your answer by adding an explanation to your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the best way, but it is different from everyone else's answers:

```
name = 'Jack'
idx = None
for ii, people in enumerate(listofpeople):
  try:
    people['Jack']
    idx = ii
    break
  except KeyError:
    continue
```